# desplazamiento de un div de un lado a otro haciendo scroll hacia abajo

Tags: javascript

Como puedo hacer para que un div me aparezca desde la izquierda al centro? O algo parecido?
Tiene que ser con javascript.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo, debes ocupar el evento onsrcroll (para detectar el scroll) y luego cambiar en alguna proporción con base en el socroll vertical la posición del elemento el resto es css

```js
const CUADRO = document.getElementById("cuadro");
function scroll(){
  CUADRO.style.transform = `translateX(${window.scrollY / 2}px)`;
}
```

```css
 #cuadro{
 position:fixed;
 left: -100px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color:orange;
 top: calc(50% - 50px);
}
body{
  height:2000px
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="scroll()">
<div id="cuadro"></div>
</body>
```